# Prop type for drawerContent in a nested drawer navigator

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

My navigigation is

```
Stack
  Drawer
    DrawerScreen1
    DrawerScreen2
  StackScreen
```

The `Drawer.Navigator` accepts a prop `drawerContent`.

`drawerContent` accepts a function of type `(props) => React.Element`.

The type of `props.navigator` in `drawerContent` function is `DrawerNavigationHelpers`. This does not allow `navigation.push`.

How can we assign a type so that `props.navigator` has both `drawer and stack` methods?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#nesting-navigators
Wont `CompositeNavigationProp` help here?

Comment: are you using react-navigation v5?